# how to make a batch file that will run on startup and then email me

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, email

I want to create a batch file that will run on windows startup.

I'm running windows 7 professional.

There is a login screen on startup, but I can bypass that if needbe but if I don't have to  that would be a bonus.

I would like the batch file to email me through any client, prefrebly hotmail, outlook, gmail, when the PC is turned on.

The reason for wanting this script is i'm accessing my router remotely to turn on my PC via WOL and I would like to be notified in the event is accessed by someone else.

Thanks

Comment: Your post actually contains two very different basic questions:

1. How to send an email with a batch file?
2. How to run a batch file on Windows startup?

I think you should better split it accordingly.

Comment: Actually I meant posting the two questions each in its own post. Well, maybe someone has already got a combined solution just for your case, but otherwise I think there might be more variety in the suggestions on each topic separately.

Answer (score 0):

Put your batch file or your batch file shortcut in this location

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

It will make your batch file run as startup which u asked for!!

and it is very difficult or completely impossible to send an email only using a batch file!! 
It is only possible via executable file(.exe etc not with cmd).

UPDATE: More over Win10 firewall will not allow such program top exist and work in that way!